# Scale and center image in variable-size div using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

http://jsfiddle.net/3qMnM/1/

**HTML**:

```
<div class="info-panel"></div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/960x1400">
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.image {
height: 100%;
width: auto;
margin-right: 200px;
}


.info-panel {
position: fixed;
width: 200px;
height: 100%;
background-color: red;
right: 0px;
}
```

I'm trying to scale images down (never up) dynamically to fit into the image-div (without cropping), which is variable in height (100%) and width (set to auto). The image also needs to be centered (vertically and horizontally) and have equal padding of a few pixels top and bottom.

There is an info panel next to the image container as you can see in the fiddle, but I'm not sure if this is relevant.

Do my statements make sense?

Thanks, I have spent way too much time experimenting with this already! :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/3qMnM/4/).

It scales down if the image is too large, but keeps the original size when it fits inside the window. In other words, it never scales up - only down.

It is a combination of CSS and some jQuery:

This short JS centers the image vertically:

```
function verticallyCenterImage(){
    var $img = $('.image img'),
        windowHeight = $(window).outerHeight();

    if($img.height() < windowHeight){
        var delta = windowHeight - $img.height();
        $img.css('margin-top', (delta / 2) + 'px');
    }else{
        $img.attr('style', '');
    }
}
```

And this line of CSS keeps the image centered horizontally:

```
.image {
    padding-right: 200px;
    text-align: center;    /* <- this one */
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

And to keep the original size of the image, I just set the max height and width on the `img` inside the `.image` class, like so:

```
.image img {
    max-width: 96%;
    max-height: 96%;
    margin: 2%;
}
```

You can adjust the size and margins to your needs, just remember to keep them in relation too each other :)

Comment: Awesome, that seems to do exactly the right thing - thanks! There's one thing I forgot though: The image-container height does not equal the window height in my final version. How would I go about calculating the height of the div instead of the whole window?

Comment: @Lennart glad to help :) You can get the height by using another selection than `window` for the `windowHeight` variable, for example `windowHeight = $("#my-wrapper-div").outerHeight()`

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing px with %. If you want to achieve that only by CSS, you need to use % for both widths:

```
.image {
    width: 85%;
}

.image img {
    width: 100%;
}

.info-panel {
    position: fixed;
    width: 15%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    right: 0px;
}
```

... otherwise, you have to use JS to calculate the current available width on the left side and assing it the .image div:

HTML

```
<div class="info-panel"></div>
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/960x1400" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.image {
    min-height: 600px;
    width: auto;
}

.image img {
    width: 100%;
}

.info-panel {
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    right: 0px;
}
```

JS (jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.image')
        .css('min-height', 'auto')
        .height($(window).height())
        .width($(window).width() - $('.info-panel').width())
    ;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you expand on the JS solution? E.g., how would I go about centering the image vertically? Could you put that into the fiddle, too?

Comment: Great. That seems to crop the image though, while I would like it to down-scale dynamically (changing when I resize the browser, and not cropping). Any ideas for that? :)

Answer (score 0):

Some of the techniques discussed here could work for you:
http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

The trick there is to use table elements, or CSS 2.1 table display.

Edit: More approaches here: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Comment: Thanks, great resource. I knew of the first one, but I didn't figure out centering in combination with the scaling yet. Will definitely read through these again, although I'm sure that this will require a JS solution.